# Saving Picture taken from camera while making a directory (Android App)

Tags: android, image, directory, save

So Im trying to do 4 things:
1) Take a photo
2) load it in the ImageView
3) Make a new Directory
4) Save the Image in that directory.

The Problem is here:

```
    File path =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                 (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(path, "MyCameraApp");
```

for some reason it is not making a new file called MyCameraApp.

and

I keep getting threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41631ba8).

here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private Uri fileUri;
ImageView iv;
private Camera mCamera;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);            
    }
 });      
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)

        {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    } 
}
   /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
     return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(path, "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.


    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name


    File mediaFile = null;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + /*File.separator +*/ "IMG_1" +".tif");
        Log.d("MyCameraApp", "DONE");
   }
    else {
        Log.d("MyCameraApp", "NOT DONE!");
        return null;
    }
    return mediaFile;
}

protected void onPause(){

    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}       

private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The StackTrace:

```
 03-10 17:14:39.708: I/Process(9786): Sending signal. PID: 9786 SIG: 9

 03-10 18:04:04.248: D/MyCameraApp(13459): failed to create directory

 03-10 18:04:04.248: D/AndroidRuntime(13459): Shutting down VM

 03-10 18:04:04.248: W/dalvikvm(13459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception(group=0x41631ba8)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459): Process: com.example.irisrec, PID: 13459

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.irisrec/com.example.irisrec.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: file

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:444)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at com.example.irisrec.Main.getOutputMediaFileUri(Main.java:80)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at  com.example.irisrec.Main.onCreate(Main.java:38)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

03-10 18:04:04.258: E/AndroidRuntime(13459):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You've given requirements, you've pasted a mountain of code, you want us to do debugging for you… Narrow down the code which is most likely the problem spot and give some more detains so we can answer it easier.

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: do you have read and write permissions in your manifest?

Comment: I have the Write one which, on the Andorid development site, says if it can write, it should be able to read too. All the Permissions are right.